# python scraping reuters site...bad xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, screen-scraping

I am trying to do something which appeared to be simple...I am trying to scrape company names of reuters list from this link:

http://www.reuters.com/finance/markets/index?symbol=us!spx&sortBy=&sortDir=&pn=

however, I just can't access the company names! Really, after playing around with a lot of xpath queries, I have problems accessing the table. I am trying to grab the names such as "3M company" and "Abbott Laboratories"

Here are snippets of code I have used:

```
scrape = []
companies =[]
import lxml
import lxml.html
import lxml.etree

urlbase = 'http://reuters.com/finance/markets/index?symbol=us!spx&sortBy=&sortDir=&pn='
for i in range(1:18):
    url = urlbase+str(i)
    content = lxml.html.parse(url)
    item = content.xpath('XPATH HERE')
    ticker = [thing.text for thing in item]
```

Here are the xpaths i have been playing with:

```
'//*[@id="topContent"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tr[2]/td[1]/a'
'//*[@id="topContent"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a
'/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/a'
'/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/table/tr[3]/td/a'
```

I have tried accessing that one particular table through:
`'//table[@class="dataTable sortable"]'`, but have not had any luck

can anyone help? I feel like this is something that someone who knows what they are doing will be able to fix rather quickly
THANKS!

Comment: aren't you skipping the form tag that's inside the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you're trying to scrape has a form inside the table. The correct xpath should be `'//table[@class="dataTable sortable"]/form/tr/td[1]/a'`

Also, you probably have a typo in your code, it should be `range(1,18)` instead of `range(1:18)`. Here's the final code that works on my side:

```
scrape = []
companies =[]
import lxml
import lxml.html
import lxml.etree

urlbase = 'http://reuters.com/finance/markets/index?symbol=us!spx&sortBy=&sortDir=&pn='
for i in range(1,18):
    url = urlbase+str(i)
    content = lxml.html.parse(url)
    item = content.xpath('//table[@class="dataTable sortable"]/form/tr/td[1]/a')
    ticker = [thing.text for thing in item]
    print ticker
```

Comment: Hey Huy,thanks a TON! I could have sworn I tried this combination, but I guess not. I appreciate it.