# Python scraping xpath not working with specific sites/tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, urllib2, lxml

I am having trouble trying to scrape data from a table at the url:

http://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/indx-bovespa/?intraday&size=600

It refers to intraday market data.
Based on previous examples and the xpath tags provided by firebug, I wrote the code below, but both the tr_nodes and td_content return empty lists:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
uol = urllib2.urlopen("http://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/indx-bovespa/?intraday&size=600")
t = uol.read()
html = etree.HTML(t)
tr_nodes = html.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/table/tbody/tr")
td_content = [[td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')] for tr in tr_nodes]
```

I read the question below from Stack Overflow:

[python scraping reuters site...bad xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907469/python-scraping-reuters-site-bad-xpath)

and tried its solution adapted to my needs:

```
import lxml
import lxml.html
import lxml.etree

url = 'http://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/bolsas/indx-bovespa/?intraday&size=600'

content = lxml.html.parse(url)
item = content.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/table/tbody/tr/td")
ticker = [thing.text for thing in item]
print ticker
```

The same problem occurred.
In fact, when I tried writing the whole url content to a text file, I could not find the td nodes I wanted to scrape. Could it be a dinamic table/form that cannot be scraped with the libraries I used, or is it just my ignorance?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When viewing the source, you can tell that there are no `<table>` elements in the actual HTML. This means that the source that Python is grabbing lacks any of the elements you are looking for. The table content is likely being inserted after the page is loaded by Javascript.

You will likely need a headless browser to download and update the content accordingly, or find the direct sources of the tables.